# ExceptionInInitializerError whenever I set the value of static variable in another frame

Tags: java, exception, static

I've created three static variables in a certain class with setters and getters to deal with them. Whenever I call the setters/getters or invoke the static variables directly (when making them public) in a Jframe i get this exception.
those static variables and methods are in a class called Validation and declared as follow: (one of them)

```
public static int valid;
   public static int getValid() {
    return valid;
}

public static void setValid(int valid) {
    Validation.valid = valid;
}
```

....

Afterwards, I call them in a Jframe source code to be executed when clickign a button:
if(flag){

```
        Validation.setValid(0);
        Validation.setInvalid(0);
       
    try {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The process might take a while, Please Wait and don't close the program!\n");
        Validation.URLsValidation(link, 0, depth, "????");
        OutputFrame f = new OutputFrame(Validation.getValid(),Validation.getInvalid());
        this.hide();
        f.setVisible(true);
        
        //open new frame of output wit hvalue of valid and invalid in it
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(InputFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(InputFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

...

can anybody tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Looks like `setInvalid(0)` is not defined. Please post more code and exception that you are getting.

Comment: It is  Defined actually. I'll post more code for clarification.